# Creating a custom date based counter (on yearly basis, on monthly basis, ...)

Tags: moqui

I need to prepare a "counter" for creating IDs based on a specific mask with   automatically incremented counter (yearly based). Something like "10${myYear}/${myCounter(myYear)}-FP" where the ID for the first document in 2016 would be **1016/001-FP**:

1. "10" is a fix string that does not change,
2. "16" is the the yy of current year > ${myYear},
3. "/" is a fixed string again,
4. "001" is the first item for the actual year > ${myCounter(myYear)} - the counter would start from 1 on the beginning of each year and automatically incremented each time a new item is created (pulled from),
5. "-FP" is again a fixed string.

Does counter-handler have to be custom coded or is there anything similar included?

Comment: It would have to be custom built. If this is for an invoice you would change or override the invoice create services to set the invoiceId instead of using the default ID generation.

Comment: OK, got it. I will code the string generator. If it's general enough, I will share it.